# I have a websocket server in springboot with stomp and I want to send a message and receive another as feedback

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, okhttp, ktor

I have a websocket server in springboot with stomp and I want to send a message and receive another as feedback

But my websocket client is android kotlin with jetpack compose ui, I already tried using Okhttp and oi.ktor
I will show the structure of my classes:

Okhttp client:

```
val webSocketListener = MyWebSocketListener()
webSocketManager = WebSocketManager(webSocketListener)
webSocketManager.connectWebSocket("ws://192.168.18.8:8080/gs-guide-websocket")
val stompMessage = "SEND\n" +
        "destination:/app/hello\n" +
        "content-type:application/json\n\n" +
        "{\"name\":\"Hello, WebSocket!\"}"
webSocketManager.sendMessage(stompMessage)
val received="SUBSCRIBE\n" +
    "destination:/topic/greetings\n" + // Substitua pelo destino apropriado
    "id:1\n\n"
webSocketManager.sendMessage(received)
```

My webSocketListener:

```
class MyWebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response)
        println("WebSocket Connection Opened ${response.code}")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
        println("Received message: $text")
    }

    override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
        println("WebSocket Connection Closed: $code, $reason")
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
        println("WebSocket Connection Failure: ${t.message}")
    }



}
```

My WebSocketManager

```
class WebSocketManager(private val listener: WebSocketListener) {

    val client: OkHttpClient
    var webSocket: WebSocket? = null

    init {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY // Defina o nível de log que deseja, como BASIC, HEADERS ou BODY
        }

        client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor) // Adicione o interceptor de log aqui (opcional)
            .build()
    }

    fun connectWebSocket(serverUrl: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJSYWZhZWwiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTUzNDg2ODEsImV4cCI6MTY5NTQzNTA4MX0.UM9G3tL1HBoP8JZkxlj-FjXq1Z3SB_ErhfZh47PK9sE")
            .url(serverUrl)
            .build()

        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
    }


    fun sendMessage(content: String) {

        webSocket?.send(content)


    }

    fun disconnectWebSocket() {
        webSocket?.close(1000, "Goodbye!")
    }


}
```

It connects and disconnects but when I send the message and subscribe it does not enter the onMessage method

So I tried using the lib oi.ktor

```
val client = HttpClient {
        install(WebSockets)
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val topic = "topic/greetings"
        val session = client.webSocketSession(
            method = HttpMethod.Get,
            host = "192.168.18.8",
            port = 8080,
            path = "/gs-guide-websocket"
        )

        if(session.isActive){

            try {
                while (isActive) {
                    // Enviar a mensagem JSON para o servidor
                    session.send(Frame.Text("SUBSCRIBE\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/topic/greetings\n\n"))

                    // Envie uma mensagem para o servidor
                    session.send(Frame.Text("SEND\ndestination:/app/hello\ncontent-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8\n\n{ \"name\": \"Olá, servidor!\" }"))

                    println("Mensagem do servidor: conectado")
                    val frame = session.incoming.receive()
                    println("Mensagem do servidor: ${frame.data}")
                    if (frame is Frame.Text) {
                        val message = frame.readText()
                        println("Mensagem do servidor: $message")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Erro ao conectar-se ao servidor WebSocket: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

    }
```

It connects and disconnects but when I send the message and subscribe it doesn't work receive

Finally, follow the websocket server in springboot

```
WebSocketConfig:

Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket");
    }

}
```

GreetingController:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting hello(HelloMessage message) {
        String v = message.getName(); // Acesse o campo 'message' da classe HelloMessage
        // Processar a mensagem recebida e retornar uma resposta, se necessário
        return new Greeting("Servidor: " + v);
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful

Comment: In the OkHttp case, you sent the `SUBSCRIBE` frame after the `SEND` so I guess it's expected you don't receive anything. Did you try swapping those?

Comment: For the Ktor case, what happens exaclty? Does the call to `receive` hang?

Comment: Also if you're looking for a proper STOMP client for Kotlin (instead of writing the frames as strings and managing subscriptions yourself), allow me to suggest my Krossbow library: https://github.com/joffrey-bion/krossbow

Comment: What does your server logs say? Do you have any idea if the message reaches the server, and it's the response that fails, or if the message is not even parsed by the server.

Comment: I changed SUBSCRIBE and SEND but I don't get anything @Joffrey

Comment: for the Ktor I want to send and receive websocket response @Joffrey

Comment: Do you have an example site on how to use the Krossbow library? @Joffrey

Comment: There is an extensive documentation website linked in the readme of the repo: https://joffrey-bion.github.io/krossbow/. Also that's what [seven-wonders](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/seven-wonders) uses, if you want a real life example

Comment: Thanks.
I followed this examplelink but I can't import the StompClient class, do you have any idea why? @Joffrey

Comment: @RafaelSouza I think this discussion is out of scope of this question. If you have questions about or issues with Krossbow, feel free to create issues or discussions in the GitHub repository. As for your current SO question, you haven't detailed much what happens exactly in the Ktor case. You said receive "doesn't work" - does it hang? does it crash? does it complete but doesn't print anything?

Comment: In the case of Ktor it crashes if I use runBlocking if I use GlobalScope.launch it doesn't crash but it doesn't print anything. I'll look at your repository and try using krossbow and then I'll give you feedback @Joffrey

Comment: Thanks! @Joffrey Perfect! I can send and receive messages